# Webflow authentication integration with private API

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, integration, webflow

The company I work for has an web application built with Angular, that has user authentication. 
We also have a blog built with Webflow for simplicity.

The thing is, we want to create special pages on our blog only for premium users. For that, a user would need to sign in on the blog (webflow) using the same account they use on the main web application. After that, the blog would also need to know if they should have access to said pages (is a premium user), and then allow them to access such areas.

I've been looking for information about this, but I've been unable to locate a clear answer. I tried following [this](https://developers.webflow.com/oauth?shell#), but the GET request for `https://webflow.com/oauth/authorize` (using my own clientID) returns their home page. This can be seen on the printscreen below:
[image]

The request has the following format: `https://webflow.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code`. It redirects twice (code 301 and 302), then just returns me their homepage.

In fact, I'm not even sure this oauth integration would solve my problem. Is this even achievable using webflow?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this problem ... I'm speaking to webflow support, but would love to understand if others have solved this.

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this problem.